# Hourly aggregation from timestamp field in Elasticsearch and Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is it possible to retrieve hourly buckets from timestamp field using terms aggregation and inline script using elasticsearch Rest HL client.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/hourly-aggregation-for-timestamp-and-java-api-irrespective-of-date/109575

**How can we achieve the below query using Elasticsearch Java HL Rest client ?**

```
# script in terms aggs.
GET /pixeluidevent/uidevent/_search
{
"size": 0, 
"query": {
"bool": {
    "must": [ { "match": { "name": "testName"  }}]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "BY_DAYOFWEEK": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "inline": "doc['eventTime'].date.hourOfDay"
        }
       }
    }
   }
}
```

Part of Response

```
"buckets": [
    {
      "key": "6",
      "doc_count": 36821
    },
    {
      "key": "0",
      "doc_count": 34000
    },
    {
      "key": "3",
      "doc_count": 30153
    },
    {
      "key": "2",
      "doc_count": 29452
    }
  ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Implemented it using stored Script.

```
// Code 
Script _script = new Script(ScriptType.STORED, "painless", "doc['eventTime'].date.dayOfWeek", new HashMap<>());

TermsAggregationBuilder termsAggBuilderForDOW = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_day_of_week").script(_script);
termsAggBuilderForDOW.size(7); // 7 size
```

PFA link for details on this.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/hourly-aggregation-for-timestamp-and-java-api-irrespective-of-date/109575/8